# Easy Struts Plug-in requires 'org.eclipse.update.ui.forms

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, struts, helios

I can't install easy struts plugin in eclipse helios. I faced with next:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Easy Struts plugin 0.6.3 (com.cross.easystruts.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.6.3)
  Missing requirement: Easy Struts plugin 0.6.3 (com.cross.easystruts.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.6.3) requires 'org.eclipse.update.ui.forms 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Any ideas? thanx

Answer (score 1):

Easy Struts is a *very* old tool that was written for Eclipse 2.x. I'm pretty sure it is no longer supported. The `org.eclipse.update.ui.forms` plugin is not part of Eclipse any more (it hasn't been for at least 6 or 7 years), so you simply can't install that version of Easy Struts into any recent version of Eclipse.

By the way, the first link when you google for `org.eclipse.update.ui.forms` would answer this question.